# Java.Покажите грамотную передачу объекта от клиента к серверу

Tags: java, клиент-сервер, объекты, serializable

Хочу передавать от клиент к серверу объект, нашел кучу примеров, понял что нужен обжектстрим поток и какой метод надо вызвать.Но такое дело, если я хочу по нажатию на кнопку в другом классе передавать объекты этого другого класа, как мне грамотно это сделать?

**СЕРВЕР**

```
startB.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        thread = new Thread(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {

                try {
                    int i = 0; // счётчик подключений
                    server = new ServerSocket(6666, 0,
                            InetAddress.getByName("localhost"));
                    System.out.println("server is started");
                    // слушаем порт
                    while (true) {
                        // ждём нового подключения, после чего запускаем обработку клиента
                        // в новый вычислительный поток и увеличиваем счётчик на единичку
                        new NewConnection(i, server.accept());
                        i++;
                        System.out.println(server.getInetAddress());

                    }
                } catch (Exception e) {
                } // вывод исключений

            }
        });
        thread.setDaemon(true);
        thread.start();

    }
});

public class NewConnection extends Thread {
    ClientsMessage msg = null;
    Socket s;
    int num;

    NewConnection(int num, Socket s) {
        this.num = num;
        this.s = s;

        setDaemon(true);
        setPriority(NORM_PRIORITY);
        start();
        System.out.println("Got client");
        try {
            ServerProgram.inStr = s.getInputStream();
            ServerProgram.inObject = new ObjectInputStream(ServerProgram.inStr);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

public void run() {
    while(true)
    {  
        try{
            msg = (ClientsMessage) ServerProgram.inObject.readObject();
            System.out.println(msg.name + " " + msg.surname);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Посмотрите retrofit, там с сериализацией/десериализацией все очень хорошо http://square.github.io/retrofit/

Comment: Забейте на стандартную сериализацию Java. Используйте сторонние библиотеки: xstream, jackson, gson, avro, kryo, protobuf

Comment: Да, и как у вас устроен "клиент-сервер"? Голые сокеты?

Comment: Вот про новые технологии надо будет почитать, просто я только начал.
Ну соккеты не голый и уже получается передавать объект но очень криво.Сейчас код дам

Comment: Сейчас я пробую сделать так что бы сервер вовремя заметил мой объект, иначе вылетает куча Ексепшенов с монитором и нулевым ссылками , так как пока я ввожу данные (логинюсь) объекта нет,как его ждать ?